# Error with Joomla 3.x.x Shortcode plugin and module

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I want to write a Joomla add-in for articles that I can add a count down timer. I would like to be able to run it using, for example, shortcode `[countdowntimer date = "23-9-2017" time = "13:42"]`. I do not know just how can I add parameters to the shortcode and move them to my module. Replacing `[countdowntimer]` on my counter I've already done.

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die();

class plgContentShortcode extends JPlugin
{  
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
    function onContentPrepare ($context, $article, $params, $limitstart)
    {
    // preg_match("/([[]countdowntimer(.*)[]])/", $article->text, $tmp, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    // I'm trying to extract parameters in this way

    // preg_match("/date=\"([0-9-]+)\"/", $tmp[2][0], $return_tmp['date'], PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); //date
    // preg_match("/time=\"([0-9:]+)\"/", $tmp[2][0], $return_tmp['time'], PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); // time

    $article->text = preg_replace('/([[]countdowntimer(.*)[]])/', '{loadmodule mod_countdowntimer}', $article->text);
    return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the title you mentioned that you have a "error". But you don't say what the exact problem is with your code (beside that it doesn't work).
Instead of coding you're own plugin, you can use a existing extension for this: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/modules-anywhere/. This extension can do exactly what you want.

But if you like to create you're own plugin, take a look at the `JModuleHelper` class to load the module with parameters (see: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModuleHelper.html). The result of `JModuleHelper::renderModule` is a string that can be append to `$article->text`

Comment: Just saw that you mentioned the problem. Sorry, read it to fast :-)